# is there a way to use mysql binary operator in doctrine2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

is there any way to do a binary comparison in doctrine? or do i have to build my own DQL query?

like the mysql binary operator ( reference:   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine does not have BINARY function [see the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#functions-operators-aggregates)

But you can implement NativeQuery [native query docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

Comment: i was trying to avoid native queries, the problem i have, is when i search some entity by some string field i was getting wrong results, because for some reason ñ = n for the function findByField... thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: @Erwin You are welcome. And that's weird. I use utf8_unicode_ci as strings encoding in MySQL and `<meta charset="utf-8">` in HTML, and I've never faced a problem with comparing non ASCII characters.

Comment: i'm using utf8_general_ci, i think i'm going to update to utf8mb4, and maybe the unicode collate, instead of general.